# 50 ksps ADC for Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: pi-4, analog-to-digital, real-time

I need to capture 4 Analog signals at a sample rate close to 50ksps. From some posts I have read that this would be unfeasible through SPI or I2C. Is there any recommended ADC chip or breakout board for this purpose that I can easily integrate with The RPi4?

Thanks

Comment: How about these? https://www.analog.com/en/parametricsearch/10826#/.

Comment: Just gloomy Sunday afternoon lock down goggling: (1) 
"AD9262 SPI Dual Channel 16-Bit, 10MHz, 30 MSPS Sigma-Delta ADC Datasheet - Analog Devices":
https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD9262.pdf. Cheers.

Comment: Finding suitable hardware will not be the problem.  The problem will be the software processing required to handle circa 200k SPI or I2C transactions per second.  The Pi may not be the most appropriate choice for your task.